# Push Notifications with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I've been trying to work with push notifications on Parse. Right now I have an app running on my phone and a couple friend of mines. I try to send out a notification to everyone but my phone is the only one that receives it. Does anyone have an idea on what I should look into to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It must be in pre-review mode. For Facebook Login, for example, you should assign testers to use before review. Have you tried turning on 'In Production'? Also try adding collaborators.